# [Text Based RPG]: Using boolean values from classes to determine actions in other classes/functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently working on a text based RPG, and I have a question or two about booleans, classes, and how to reference booleans from other classes, along with clarification on how to use classes properly.  Currently, I have a class with some function that determine certain values in rooms, and based off the values, the player will find gold, fight an enemy, etc.  Here's a small example of what I'm trying to do, and I'd like advice on how to better use classes, or if I'm possibly misunderstanding classes as well.

```
class room_properties():
    def __init__(self):
        self.gold = gold
        self.item = item
        self.enemy = enemy

    def room_a_prop(self):
        gold = False
        item = False
        enemy = False

class area_1():
    def room_a(self):
        r_p = room_properties()
        if r_p.room_a_prop.gold == False and r_p.room_a_prop.item == False and r_p.room_a_prop.enemy == False:
            #do this stuff
```

My first question is when I reference the values of room_a_prop, is there a better way than listing `'r_p.room_a_prop.gold == False and and and and and'`.  Is there a better way to reference those variables, or do I have to list them out like that?  Am I using classes correctly as well?  Is there a better way to set up values for each room and reference them later?

Thanks!!

Comment: I think the answer is "no", you are not using classes correctly. I'm not clear why area_1 is a class, it sounds like it should be an instance. Instead of "room_properties" why not "Room"? You can then sub-class Room for different Room types, or instantiate it for specific rooms.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example of what you are trying to accomplish? I'm pretty sure `r_p.room_a_prop.gold` is going to give you an error since gold isn't an attribute of the function. Robert's comment is spot on; it's not clear what your intention is and it's hard to frame an answer without knowing more.